# How to forward to different domain based on database field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

A feature of our app is certain "white label" domains, but what I'd like to do is if a user doesn't have the white label feature enabled, the then white label domains would just forward to our root domain (no need to retain sub-directories).

So, since it would need to check the database first (ie. `@account.white_label?`), and THEN forward, where would that check need to go and what request variable would I use?

For example, I might say:

```
unless @account.white_label?
  # check to see what current domain is
  # if it's a "white label" domain and this account does not have that feature enabled,
  # then redirect_to primary-domain.com
ebd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do something like this in your application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :check_if_account_supports_white_label

  def check_if_account_supports_white_label
    domain = request.env['HTTP_HOST']
    unless Account.where(:domain => domain).first.supports_white_label?
     redirect_to some_url
    end
  end
end
```